# Saving a translation

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-1.3, cakephp

I've setup localization for my cakePHP application and I'm having a problem when saving.

I have the following schema

```
id  name
```

And another field `description` which will be translatable.

When I do the following code:

```
$this->Test->locale = "en_US";
$this->Test->set("name", "test 1");
$this->Test->set("description", "desc US");
$this->Test->save();
```

works fine (i.e. name gets saved in the above schema & description with the correct details is saved in the i18n table) - the primary key inserted is **1 - BUT**

when I try to add a new translation by executing the following code:

```
$this->Test->locale = "fr_FR";
$this->Test->id = 1;
//$this->Test->set("name", "test 1");
$this->Test->set("description", "desc FR");
$this->Test->save();
```

i.e. leaving out the `name` field, nothing gets saved!! I would expect to have another row in the i18n table with the new translation of fr_FR description.

**IF I DO NOT COMMENT OUT THE `name` FIELD, IT WILL BE SAVED BUT IT WILL UPDATE THE `name`
FIELD TOO WHICH THAT SHOULD NOT BE TRANSLATED!!**

Any idea why please?

Answer (score 0):

Would not that be simply a problem of validation? If you wish to bypass the validation method, pass `null` as second parameter of the save method.